# Is def file is necessary to define

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, dll, dllimport

Is there necessary to define def file in the vc++(unmanaged) dll.If I do'nt want to define the def file then how can I create the dll without def file.

Answer (score 2):

The `.def` file is the module definition file. It controls which symbols are exported from the dll. The `.def` file is not absolutely necessary - the `__declspec(dllexport)` keyword can be used to specify exports instead.

In general, using `__declspec(dllexport)` is easier with C++, as exporting a C++ symbol using a `.def` requires an understanding of the compiler's name mangling scheme.

Comment: I changed my function decleration as you said.and delete the entry from the def file but the problem is already exist,when I execute my exe the message show the the ordinal 213 is not fount in the dll.

Comment: Check the exports with dumpbin or Dependency Walker.